# Minimize $\mathrm{Tr}((G^TG)^{-1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

I have been trying to minimize $\mathrm{Tr}((G^TG)^{-1})$ using CVX. I have formulated it in the following SDP structure, using Schur Complement. Here is the formulation:
$$\mathbf{minimise} \ \ t \\\mathbf{subject\ \ to}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}  I & G \\G^T & -X \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \qquad \begin{bmatrix} Z & I \\ I & X \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \qquad \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(Z)\leq t$$

For the first matrix (the matrix with $G$ in it), the inequality inferred by Schur complement is $X \preceq -G^TG$ (this requires $I$ to be positive definite, which it is by definition)

For the other matrix, the inequality inferred by Schur complement is $Z \succeq X^{-1}$ (this requires $Z$ to be positive definite)

So, I did plug this in CVX but the result does not seem legitimate. 
Can someone please tell me if my formulation is correct?

Comment: But if there are no more constraints then it must be $0$ because $G^TG$ is PSD as well as its inverse. So, the minimum of sum of the eigenvalues is $0$.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the reply :)

Comment: Interesting... Is it true that the inverse of a PSD is also a PSD? PSDs can have eigenvalues of zero tho, thus making the inverse not possible (singular), am I wrong to think that?

When plugging this into CVX, and setting a fixed $G$ (just to see if CVX can handle it), I get an optimal value of infinity and find that $Z \neq  (G^TG)^{-1}$, but this is not correct, $Z$ must equal $(G^TG)^{-1}$

Would it help to post my code?

EDIT: Would you say my formulation is correct tho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is wrong, which sort of is hinted by the obvious problem that the first constraint forces $X$ to be negative semidefinite, while the seconds forces it to be positive semidefinite

You have $Z \geq (G^TG)^{-1}$, and you then introduce a new variable $X$ to model $G^TG$. However, I don't see why you introduce the constraint $X \preceq -G^TG$. What you must have is $Z \succeq X^{-1} \succeq (G^TG)^{-1}$, which means $X \preceq G^TG$, a non-convex set which cannot be written as a linear semidefinite constraint.

A simple way to realize that this cannot be cast as a linear semidefinite program is the fact that the function basically is $1/x^2$ in the scalar case, easily seen to be non-convex.

Comment: Grr, I can't believe I missed the easy test. I think because it resembled other LMI-compatible functions I didn't think to look for it.

Comment: I see what you mean about $X$ having opposing semidefiniteness constraints. I did not notice that for this formulation. If you haven't noticed, I have learned this technique from an old reply you posted to this link: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/matlabs-cvx-package-to-minimize-mathrmtraces-mathrmtraces-2

I have been trying to understand how you choose bounds for $X$ and $Z$. You say that I should have: $Z \succeq X^{-1} \succeq (G^TG)^{-1}$. How did you conclude that? I know my objective function cannot be formulated as such (thanks to your help) but I am just curious.

Comment: Also, if I may add, how does one proceed with such an objective function? Or what path should I travel now? I still want to see if this is optimizable... I will be reading on nonconvex optimization I guess.

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder if restricting the domain (what $G$ can be) will turn this problem into a convex problem. 

The reason I say this is because, looking at that scalar case you provided, if we restrict $x$ to be positive then, our function is convex... right?

Comment: Sir, I would like to know whether my reasoning is correct. I understand that it can not be solved using SDP, but can it solved analytically? Like what I have mentioned in my earlier comment that $G^TG$ is PSD so its inverse. So, the minimum value will be $0$.

Comment: I think, the statement you made above along with my assumption that the objective function above being convex, will be correct IF we restrict the domain.

The inverse of a PSD way result in a singular eigenvalue if the original PSD had an eigenvalue of 0. You can prevent this by restricting the domain. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, the scalar problem is convex on the restricted domain, but that will not help you as you will not be able to Schur-complement your way out of this model, as far as I can see

Comment: Is it possible to model the $tr(X^{-1})$ using this technique? I can't seem to do so. I am trying to give this a go with Yalmip.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want to minimize it, yes, just introduce an upper bound variable on $X^{-1}$ and apply a Schur complement to get an LMI

Comment: Thank you. For this to work I would have to assume $X$ to be positive definite, right?

Comment: The trace would be infinite if X only was semidefinite, hence semidefinite would never be optimal

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you! :)